# Python script suddendly becomes stuck when using multiprocessing.Queue()

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to create a complex CAD geometry in Python, using pythonocc-core. To speed up the calculation I'm using the built in parallel computation for cutting holes in a complex solid. To overcome my memory limit I'm dividing the cutting procedure in batches, and, to avoid a previously encountered memory leaking, I'm using multiprocessing.Process() to conduct the cutting operation in a separate process. The simplest way to communicate the result was, at first, to write the partial geometry to a step file. However, I wanted to try to directly return the result of the cut, without writing a file.

My code looks something like this:

```
QQ=multiprocessing.Manager().Queue() # I have also tried with multiprocessing.Queue() but the result is the same

for block in list_blocks:
    p1=multiprocessing.Process(target=cutting_function, args=(result, block, QQ, #others)
    p1.start()

    result=QQ.get()
    p1.join()
```

And the function is something like this:

```
def cutting_function(result, block, QQ, #others):
    #various calculations
    QQ.put(result)
```

The programs performs a certain (small) number of iterations and then suddendly seems stuck and doesn't proceed with the next iteration (I waited a huge amount of time compared to the previous iterations but no advancement)

I'm using Jupyterlab in an Anaconda environment with Python 3.11.5, using WSL2 Ubuntu on Windows 11

I've tried multiprocessing.Queue() and multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()
I've tried to create the QQ once, outside the for cycle, but also to recreate it in every cycle
I've also tried to join p1 before QQ.get() but no differences.

Comment: Hard to tell without a [mre] (no need for your cutting process. Reproduce the problem with elementary one-line functions). One remark tho: as is, unless I miss something, you run process one after each other. So it is not really multiprocessing. Right?

Comment: You need to use the Manager() as a work manager. Coding it like that won't work because the Manager() (proxy) will die. Also, the pattern you're employing doesn't really make sense as there's no advantage in running a separate process

Comment: I know that this is not a proper multiprocessing case, since I'm using only one process a a time, but as I wrote, without confining the cutting function to a different process, I was slowly leaking memory after every iteration (I don't know why)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long answer follows. Short version: I am pretty sure one of your call to the `cutting_function` ended before putting anything in the queue. So then the main process waits forever for something to be in the queue. If you know how to correct those "end without putting something in the queue" bug in `cutting_function`, then, do it, and no need to read the rest. Otherwise:...

So, if I get it correctly, you don't really want multiprocessing. You just want to isolate each call in a subprocess, to that any mess that was created by the process (memory leak) dies with it.

Needless, I suppose, to say, that it would be far better to find the reason for this memory leak and solve it.

Then what you are doing is just something like

```py
import multiprocessing

QQ=multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()

def cutting_function(arg, QQ):
    QQ.put(1000+arg)

for i in range(100):
    p1=multiprocessing.Process(target=cutting_function, args=(i, QQ))
    p1.start()
    r=QQ.get()
    p1.join()
    print(i, r)
```

Which runs without any problem, and displays 100 lines, from `0 1000` to `99 1099`. As expected I guess.
And without any sort of parallelism (even if I had a complex computation instead of 1000+arg, it would be one after each other).

Note that I skipped the manager. You don't need a manager if you have only one process.

Problem is that the way you use a queue to get the return value implies that each process put exactly one value on it.

See this other example

```py
import multiprocessing

QQ=multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()

def cutting_function(arg, QQ):
    if arg==50: return
    QQ.put(1000+arg)

for i in range(100):
    p1=multiprocessing.Process(target=cutting_function, args=(i, QQ))
    p1.start()
    r=QQ.get()
    p1.join()
    print(i, r)
```

This time it works fine and well... until we reach the 50th run. At which point it just freezes.
As it should. The 50th process runs and exits without putting anything in the queue. And then you are trying to received something from the queue. And there is nothing. So it blocks, waiting for something to be there.

Note that a variant of this example could be with this function

```py
def cutting_function(arg, QQ):
    QQ.put(math.log(49-arg))
```

My point here: the reason why you may get not value, it because one process crashes before it could return anything.
Without the run in a separate process, that crash would have crashed your whole code. But here, it is just one process that crashes. It shows an error message on the screen, but the main process still continues. And still wait for something to appear in the queue.

Which may seem surprising with your usage. One could wonder how it could expect something to appear in the queue after the process is done. But that is because your usage of the queue it not really the usual one. Normally it is supposed to be used when you run 10 processes in parallel, and, in the main process, wait for result to come, in whatever order (not necessarily in the order you started the process).

For your "monoprocessing" usage, with a very sequential: I start a process, the process end, I get the one and only result, a `Value` might be more adapted (with a default value, so that you can know, when the process is finished, that no value has been returned).

Another solution could be simply to test if the queue is empty

```py
import multiprocessing
import math

QQ=multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()

def cutting_function(arg, QQ):
    QQ.put(math.log((49-arg)**2))

for i in range(100):
    p1=multiprocessing.Process(target=cutting_function, args=(i, QQ))
    p1.start()
    if QQ.empty():
        print("no result")
    else:
        r=QQ.get()
        print(i, r)
    p1.join()
```

The 50th line shows an error (in the subprocess) and then 'no result' in the main process. But then it continues.

`multiprocessing` documentation however states that there could be an "infinitesimal time" between the `QQ.put()` and when that result is available. So, there is a slight risk (that I can't see even with millions of trials) that queue is empty for a very brief instant. With a direct `QQ.get()` it doesn't matter. That would mean that `QQ.get()` waits for an infinitesimal amount of time. With with my latter solution, that slight risk is a risk that we miss a result once. And then each `QQ.get()` gets the previous result (and the 100th result is lost).

So, another solution would be to ensure that each subprocess push something

```py
import multiprocessing
import math

QQ=multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()

def cutting_function(arg, QQ):
    try:
        QQ.put(math.log((49-arg)**2))
        return
    except:
        QQ.put('error')
        return
    QQ.put('no result')

for i in range(100):
    p1=multiprocessing.Process(target=cutting_function, args=(i, QQ))
    p1.start()
    r=QQ.get()
    print(i, r)
    p1.join()
```

Note the `return` after `QQ.put`. That is to ensure that we don't put two things in the queue. In such a simple code, no risk.
But in a more complex code, that would mean that if we reach the end (the last line of the function) that is either because we crashed, or because we forgot to put something in the queue in one case.

Those `error`/`no result` are sentinels. That ensure that there is something in the queue, even when there is nothing.

Note also that when I say "crashes" I mean a python error. One that raise an exception, and can be catched by a `try/except`.
If it is a real crash (a segfault for example. Which can happen only if you find a bug in python interpreter, or if you play with some fires, such as C-extension code, or `ctypes`), then my `except` will catch nothing, so there will be nothing in the queue. And still, the main process will still be well and alive since they are different processes.

```py
import multiprocessing
import math
import ctypes

QQ=multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()

def cutting_function(arg, QQ):
    try:
        if arg==30:
            i=ctypes.c_int(1)
            p=ctypes.pointer(i)
            x=p[-1000000000] # Should segfault
        QQ.put(math.log((49-arg)**2))
        return
    except:
        pass
    QQ.put('no result')

for i in range(100):
    p1=multiprocessing.Process(target=cutting_function, args=(i, QQ))
    p1.start()
    r=QQ.get()
    print(i, r)
    p1.join()
```

This example freezes at the 30th line. Because the 30th process segfault. So, not only did it not `QQ.put` `log(49-30)`, but it did not `QQ.put` a sentinel neither: the whole python process crashed.
But yet, the main process is still there, waiting for `QQ.get()` to find something in the queue.

So, if there is a risk that this happen, you could mix suspender and belt:

```py
import multiprocessing
import math
import ctypes

QQ=multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()

def cutting_function(arg, QQ):
    try:
        if arg==30:
            i=ctypes.c_int(1)
            p=ctypes.pointer(i)
            x=p[-1000000000] # Should segfault
        QQ.put(math.log((49-arg)**2))
        return
    except:
        pass
    QQ.put('no result')

for i in range(100):
    p1=multiprocessing.Process(target=cutting_function, args=(i, QQ))
    p1.start()
    if QQ.empty():
         time.sleep(1)
    if QQ.empty():
         print("subprocess crashed")
    else:
        r=QQ.get()
        print(i, r)
    p1.join()
```

So, if process works normally, then, there is a result if the queue.
If process forgets to return something in the queue, or raise an exception, then there is a sentinel in the queue ("no result" or "error") so there is still something in the queue.
If process completely crashes (because of a segfault for example) then, `QQ.empty` is there to see it and deal with this case.
Lastly, if that "infinitesimal amount of time" occurs, and `QQ.empty` while the process did not crashed, we give a second chance for the message to arrive (1 second is way over anything that can be qualified as "infinitesimal amount of time")

So, here, I would say, you can be pretty sure that you'll never get stuck waiting for an empty queue.

Comment: The problem was indeed a segmentation fault (or at least it should be, since the process exits with code -11). It may be caused by one of the functions in the OCC module. However, since the calculation were long, 1 second wasn't enough to have the queue not empty so i had to increase the waiting time. Would it be risky to check the queue after the process joined, so that I can firstly check the exit code?

Comment: @StefanoPizzamiglio Yes. Queue is not attached to a process (anyway, it is the same queue for all of them), and data are copied in it. You can start and join 1000 process without reading the queue once, and read all the results afterward if you'd wish (and if you have enough RAM to store all those results), So, indeed, you can join first, read result after.